# CSS - Break grid elements and stretch to widest in column

Tags: html, css, sass

I have two buttons in one row, one wider than the other. If the viewport gets too small, the buttons should "break", meaning they sit in one column. In that case the smaller button should stretch its width to the width of the wider button.

I have prepared a codepen which simulates my current stand point:

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(min-content, max-content));
  grid-gap: 16px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px 48px;
}

.stroke {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.flat {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <button class="stroke">
      <span>WIDER BUTTON</span>
    </button>
    <button class="flat">
      <span>BUTTON</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/simonmeier/pen/xxOMKQg

The texts in the buttons are dynamic, meaning I don't know what's gonna be in there, so "hard-coding" a width doesn't work.

Is this possible with plain (s)css?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex on your container instead of inline-grid.

Then by applying `flex-wrap: wrap;` the content will automatically wrap to the next line if is doesn't fit.

And putting `flex-grow: 1;` on the smaller button makes it so the button will grow to fit the container.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -16px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px 48px;
  margin: 0 16px;
}

.stroke {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
}

.flat {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <button class="stroke">
      <span>WIDER BUTTON</span>
    </button>
    <button class="flat">
      <span>BUTTON</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine until it breaks. The button with `flex-grow: 1` stretches to the full width of the viewport, after I've removed the `width` from .flat and .stroke... as I've said in the question, setting the width on the button is not an option, since i don't know what the text is going to be

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be use `flex-wrap: wrap` changing the `display` property to `flex` in `.inner` and `flex: 1 1 auto;` to your `button`.

If you want more control to your layout, consider using [@media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp).

```css
.outer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
    /*display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(min-content, max-content));*/
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /*grid-gap: 16px;*/
}
button {
    border: none;
    margin: 8px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 10px 48px;
}

.stroke {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.flat {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <button class="stroke">
            <span>WIDER BUTTON</span>
        </button>
        <button class="flat">
            <span>BUTTON</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```